# Truth Values and the Relationships Between Negated Compound Statements Conjuncted with Conjunctions

Tags: logic

I am trying to determine the truth value of the following statement:

∼(S → Q) and ∼Q • S

I am not confident in my translation of both sides of this statement. Here is my attempt:

On the left side, I believe that ∼(S → Q) reads as "it is not the case that Q is true given that S.

On the left side, it seems a bit more straightforward to me, reading "it is not the case that Q is true, but it is the case that S is true."

Could this statement be accurately be described as being logically consistent? Or valid? Logically Equivalent? Consistent/Inconsistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\neg (S \rightarrow Q) \equiv \neg (Q \lor \neg S) \equiv \neg Q \land S,$$
so assuming your $\cdot$ means conjunction, $\neg(S \rightarrow Q)$ is equivalent to $\neg Q \cdot S$.